# Wine Problems // Black Meshes and bad performance

Tags: dual-boot, wine, compression

I´ve installed the latest Ubuntu version as DualBoot with Windows XP and wanted
to play a game with Wine. So I started the Software Center, installed it and
followed the installation guide at the [Wine AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16051). It starts the launcher
without any problems, but then there seems a little problem with the shader.
It only shows black meshes instead of the textured ones. According to the
terminal output there is a problem with the compressed textures but I dont know
any solution for this problem.

A little Information to my actual Hardware:

I am using a really bad OnBoard Graphics Card but up to now it works with
Windows.

Thanks to any kind of help and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my first suggestion would be to try Playonlinux, I went over 2 years without using it. But once I installed it, it was great. It allows you to very easily manage all your Wine prefixes (your virtual C:/ drives). You can use it as intended, or you can do what I do and just use everything from its config screen. But Google will turn up plenty of resources on how to use it.

Second, If your using Intel Integrated, you can continue to try if you so choose, but Intel chips don't work to well - if at all - for games in Linux, especially wine. I have a laptop with a GMA965 that wont load anything properly similar to what you described its mostly black textures. However I had a friend with a GMA950 that would display just fine, but games would only get around 3FPS. So its a shot in the dark for Intel GPUs.

nvidia has the best Linux support at the moment, even though I'm running a AMD Radeon HD 6850 and there drivers aren't "that bad", you'll definitely find better support with nvidia.

Comment: You have guessed right with my intel chip. Ok, that means I have to switch between the systems everytime -_-. Thanks for your answer, and I will try that 'playonlinux'.